# ionic unable to add SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

Tags: android, git, cordova, ionic-framework, plugins

I am trying to use SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin in my first app development, 
https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin#web-share-api

I have tried following command :

cordova plugin add SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin

cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin.git

but It gives me same error , Anyone know what the problem is?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some plugins can install in specific versions of cordova.

so please downgrade your cordova version and try to install that plugin again.

if your cordova version is 7+, downgrade to 6.5.0

npm install -g cordova@6.5.0

Answer (score 0):

The plugin name is case sensitive, so the right one is:

cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing

Comment: Then you have a connection problem. I've tried the installation of the plugin minutes ago and it works.